# Python loop dict in assigned order

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I've run into a problem with looping through a dictionary. The following code:

```
d = {}
d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = 2
d['c'] = 3
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

Results in:

```
a 1
c 3
b 2
```

But the desired result is:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

Does anyone know how to fix the loop somehow to preserve the order that the elements were assigned in? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, normal dictionaries were designed to be unordered.  Meaning, they should not be used here.

Instead, you should use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> d['a'] = 1
>>> d['b'] = 2
>>> d['c'] = 3
>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
...     print k,v
...
a 1
b 2
c 3
>>>
```

Unlike a normal dictionary, an `OrderedDict` is guaranteed to preserve the order in which the elements were assigned.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it made me wait 10 minutes..

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary does not preserve order, so you need to sort the keys:

```
for k,v in sorted(d.iteritems,key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print k,v
```

Alternatively, use a `collections.OrderedDict` object which internally maintains a list of keys in insertion order:

```
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict()
...
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    print k,v
```